# Visual Studio Code - lagging when typing

Tags: java, ide

I have just installed Visual Studio Code together with the Java Extension Pack. However, when I opened my first file and started typing, the text I type appears after a delay - reaching up even one second. 
I have a hunch that it might be due to the number of processes going behind the editor, like real-time syntax checking, autocompletion, code hints et cetera. Perhaps the laptop I am working at simply cannot handle that much. These are the parameters of my current machine: 
Processor: Intel(R) Caleron(R) CPU N3350 (1.10 GHz) 
RAM: 4 GB 
 
I have another hunch that it may be due to the processor. 
So, are there a ways to switch off these facilities like real-time error-checking? If not, what other IDEs for Java could you reccomend? (Apart from Eclipse)

Comment: Try a different IDE

Comment: What is the reason for my question getting downvoted?

Comment: It's not really a programming question, plus the second part (which IDE should you use instead) is opinion based. See the [SO on-topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem using Visual Studio Code while using *Android Studio along with an Android Simulator in the background*, and I run *8GB RAM* and a *CPU of 3.2GHz* but when I returned to Notepad++ (I know its suicidal), to check if it is my problem or because of the IDEs, I typed in real time.

It is due to your processor as Visual Studio Code is not really recommended for "slow" CPUs. Personally I like it, although an IDE in the likes of Vim might suit you better.

Here is a link that might give some more hints:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38409

Comment: I've an Core i7 7700k with 16Gb of RAM and it's very slow too.

Comment: i have the 10980hk i9 32gb. running slowly. 16 core 5.3ghz

Comment: several seconds lag on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz 3.19 GHz with 64 GB ram. Not usable like this.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution I found was to download and install Visual Studio Code Insiders.  It's nearly identical except that it's known to lag less.  Installing this will also clear any extensions or preferences you have enabled which might be causing the lag:

https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

You may also need to run it from the command line with the --disable-gpu flag

```
code-insiders --disable-gpu
```

or

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code\ -\ Insiders.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --disable-gpu
```

depending on your OS

Comment: "disable-gpu" flag works for standard RPM-distributed vscode in Fedora either. That helped with the lagish interface issue. Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue recently. It was also lagging when saving files.

Disabling Code Actions resolved the issue for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Try The Flowing :-

- Disabling extensions.
- Update to stable version.

still not worked ? `reinstall` vs code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's related to extensions as this issue doesn't happen when all extensions are disabled. The question is **what** extension is causing this? How to find it out, _without_ manually going through all of them?

Comment: P.S. I am tired of almost all answers to anything world-wide to be "clean install", "power off and on again", and other non-solutions... Thankfully you mentioned it as the last step.

Answer (score 1):

### Please disable `Spring Boot Tools` from Pivotal!!!

This extension doesn't work well with other Java extesions.(ie. Extesion pack for Java and Language support for Java)

After disabling it, I've seen significant speed increase with Intellisense, and CPU load reduced as a result. Please get rid of the thing!!!

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, I often let the computer sleep instead of turn off and kill all processes so it was normal for me that the VS was open for a few days, the **solution was to close visual studio and reopen it.**

Answer (score 0):

maybe its the computer performance issue. i am using a laptop.

yesterday i uninstall large program (MS SQl server)

now typing speed back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I've now had this problem a number of times. As a matter of fact I just had it right now.
What solves it for me is to

1. Close VS code
2. Unpin it from my taskbar
3. Pin it back

It works well after that.

Closing and reopening VS Code has never worked for me

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was Language pack extension issue,

when i uninstall Language pack for my country, it resolved.

(updated)

try disable hardware acceleration

Disable hardware acceleration: VS Code uses hardware acceleration to improve performance, but it can sometimes cause issues with typing lag. To disable hardware acceleration, go to File > Preferences > Settings, search for "hardware acceleration" and uncheck the box.

thanks to GPT